# Recover deleted directory from /dev/vda1

Tags: data-recovery, delete, testdisk

Accidentally deleted the directory `image`.
It's path is  `/var/www/html/project/images`.

Installed the `testdisk` while executing the analyze. It says that no disk found.

So executed the command `ls /dev/`.

It doesn't shows any `sdX` drives it shows `vda` & `vda1`.

So how to recover file from `vda`.

Comment: /dev/vdX is often used for virtual disks. Are you working in an environment with virtual disks? I assume you should just use the same commands as for /dev/sdX - as it is just pointing to another kind of drive.

Comment: @dufte Yes it's digitialocean cloud server. In directory `/dev` there is no sdX.

Comment: Have you checked the official testdisk step-by-step guide (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)? Looks like it is adviced to start the application and then select a source drive from a list ... in your case most likely /dev/vda

Comment: @dufte Based on that documentation only we did. But after entered `[Create]`. It says `No hardisks found` but this server have virtual hard disk `vda1`